# iOS - thread safety and performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: ios, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I got a thread running native code in the background that fires of some callbacks every once in a while. The native callbacks call objective-C methods. For each call I am basically redrawing stuff or altering some values of my classes. So I will get lots of synchronization issues.

Is it possible to solve this by instead of having locks, just doing performSelectorOnMainThread on every callback? Will that prevent synchronization problems or is it too much of a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any drawing *must* take place on the main thread, so something like `-performSelectorOnMainThread` is going to be required, even if you are using locks.

You might also want to look into using blocks and a dispatch queue for your callbacks, as a way to handle synchronization issues without explicit locks. The Apple [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/) has a lot of information about using blocks and dispatch queues as an alternative to threads/locks. Blocks and Queues are implemented at the C level (not Objective-C), so you can easily add them to C code (I assume that's what you mean by "native") without rewriting things into Objective-C.

(Note that when using blocks for callbacks you still need to make sure that your UI drawing operations are dispatched to the main queue, so they run on the main thread.)

Comment: The drawing part is done in main thread, as i do "reloadData" on the mainthread. I was wondering if I could escape locks and such on the variables by just performing any updates on them in the mainthread aswell (such as removing/adding elements to the Array that contains all the elements, and Then reloadData on mainthread)